# How to get to the following result in second quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, many-body, second-quantization, bosons

I'm reading Piers Coleman's "Introduction to Many Body Theory" and I'm currently at the chapter for second quantization, at some point it gives what it calls an "heuristic derivation" of how many-body wavefunction operators result in having the same evolution dynamics of one-body wavefunctions. I'm sure this is a very basic step but I can't find the way he gets from (4.12) to (4.13), does he simply multiply (4.12) by $\sum_{n}|n⟩\psi_{n}(t)$? That doesn't get rid of the minus sign though.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from 4.11 and the defintion of $\langle H \rangle$
\begin{align}
\langle H \rangle &= \langle \psi | H | \psi \rangle\\
&= \left(\sum_m \psi_m^* \langle m | \right) H \left(\sum_n \psi_n |n\rangle \right)\\
&= \sum_{m,n} \psi_m^*\psi_n\langle m | H | n \rangle
\end{align}